# Getting part of the filename C#

Tags: c#, filenames

I have a file name `dayhappy_02_02345.csv`

How do I get the `02` part out to be used in a variable and also how do I get the `02345` part so that I can pass these 2 values into a variable for a function.

Using c#.

I have looked at `GetFileName` but this gets either the filename, the extention or the full file name only.

Thanks

Ste

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For that specific file name,

```
string sData = "dayhappy_02_02345.csv";
string[] sArr = sData.split('_');

string sPart1 = sArr[1];
string sPart2 = sArr[2];
```

Will do, but that's a special case, will work *only* on file names of this type

Comment: I think your answer might work, but im using a Dts.Variable and the filename with its extension is located in the variable. Will this work? Can you simply replace string sData = Dts.Variables["filenameVariable"].Value.
thanks for quick response

Comment: Ofcourse you can. Furthermore, you have to insert some validations in this code, which I haven't included in the example above

Comment: I have this at the moment:
string fileName = Dts.Variables["csvFileNames"].Value;
string[] sArray = fileName.Split('_');

                string 02345Number = sArray[1];
                string 02Number = sArray[2];


                MessageBox.Show(02345Number);
saying can not convert object to string. 
Im being really silly here I reckon and im missing syntax, but i have this: using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime; in the namespace so I dont know what would be wrong with this. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry I was being very stupid. I was missing a (). lol
thanks

Answer (score 4):

Get the file name as you've already figured out, then use [String.Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) to get the individual pieces.

Comment: I would advise against using string methods, since change of format will force you to change the code, whereas with Regex you can make the string a configuration setting, and it's more flexible and powerful anyways.

Comment: @Mr.TA - Fair enough.  I agree in general, but in this specific example, String.Split is sufficient.  This is subjective, but I like cleaner simpler code, where possible.  Also, this is obviously a very new developer, so I gave the simplest answer possible.  Learning Regular Expressions is something that needs to be done, but does he need it right now, for this case?  I was thinking baby steps before running.  But again, I DO agree with what you say in general.

Comment: The filename keeps changing but the extension doesn't, also I have the file in a dts variable. is the Regex way the best way forward?

Comment: Judging by the other answers, the splitting is more popular, who am I to argue with the PEOPLE's choice :)

Comment: @Steven The "filename keeps changing" - meaning the format of it keeps changing?

Comment: Thanks for all your help, I am indeed starting to learn C# so I appreciate all your help. I have only had a few days with it so im not comfortable with the language at the moment. However I am using it with SSIS so im hoping I can quickly get to grips with it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use Regex:

```
var match = new Regex(@".*_(\d+)_(\d+)").Match(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileNAme));
var v02 = match.Groups[0].Value;
var v02345 = match.Groups[1].Value;
```